# How to make digit detector with CV

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I am trying to detect multiple numbers in a video feed with computer vision,
theres 4 numbers on a screen I need to live update, so for example,
variable 'A' is in the top right of my screen on a video feed,
B is top left, C bottom right, D bottom left, the numbers change by the millisecond but their location on the screen remains the same, this is a video feed im trying to get using PIL and imageGrab currently,
I want to save all these floats in live updating variables, so use computer vision to detect what number is currently in a video feed (on my computer screen) and save them to variables in python, how do I do this? thanks. so if the computer screen shows A = 2.839. I want the OpenCV to detect that and store it as a float variable and update in real time(or as close as possible.)

I essentially just want to watch 4 different parts of my screen and detect what number is currently on the screen, so one second my screen shows.
A = 1.2 B = 2.2 C = 3.2 D = 4.2 the next second it shows
A = 1.3 B = 2.3 C = 3.3 D = 4.3
I want my python variables for A B C and D to live update in my code as they update on the screen, but theres 10 numbers on my screen only 4 are relevant and theyre always in the same spot on my screen.

Comment: Would you be able to show us a sample image?

Comment: It's very hard to detect things we can't see - your question needs an image. You should also show your current best attempt at coding it yourself. Also, it is unclear what the actual issues are... is it grabbing the screen? or detecting the digits? or passing them to your program?

Answer (score 0):

Since the position of the digits is fixed, 60% of your work is already done. Now based on what you are saying, I am assuming that the font of the numbers is the same. If the font is also same, jackpot ! you can simply use opencv as find contours, detects the numbers are decimal points and based or any simple features like hog features on a very simple CNN you can predict each and every digit, arrange them in sequence with respect to co-ordinates. Boom.. your job is done.

If the font is different, you can still try to use the mnist digit recognition model [Very well explained here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-develop-a-convolutional-neural-network-from-scratch-for-mnist-handwritten-digit-classification/). If this also doesn't work, you need to work on the training by urself.